# Selecting a GROUP BY statement only when a predicate is true on all grouped fields

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
-------------
| id  |  A  |
-------------
|  1  |  2  |
|  1  |  5  |
|  1  |  6  |
|  2  |  6  |
|  2  |  9  |
-------------
```

How can I select all ids that have values of A that don't contain certain numbers, like I don't want any id that have A IN (9,-1,20), for example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you want only ID 1 because for ID 2 there is a value of A which is IN (9,-1,20) this is what you want:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.A
  FROM my_table t1
  LEFT JOIN my_table t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
   AND t2.A IN (9, -1, 20)
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT id
  FROM my_table t1
 WHERE NOT EXIST (
       SELECT NULL
         FROM my_table t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
          AND t2.A IN (9, -1, 20)
       )
```

Comment: Yep! That was it!!! Thank you very much! I thought this was a "group by" problem!